# Count points based on unique values in column

Tags: r

**EDIT:**
below was extremely useful, so I've been playing around with this for a few hours. Eventually I ended up trying something that didn't work: from the mean of the points per id, I tried to only include the last (for example) 5 clicks/pageviews per id. The code I used is:

> megatest<-aggregate(points ~ session_id, pointsperid, mean, FUN=tail, n=5)

However, it only produces a table looking like:

```
id    points
1     c(20,0)
2     c(20,10,20,100,20)
```

Instead of summing them and producing the mean. I'm curious, is there any way to work around this? Thanks in advance! (and apologies for so many new questions in this question, but R is getting me really excited).

---

Hi experienced R users,

I'm new to R, so my apologies if the answer is straightforward or if I'm not being clear.

I created a dataframe of about 500,000 observations of clickstream data across 16 variables. Two of these columns are 'id' and 'assigned points'

Where 'id' indicates an internet session id, and 'points' the number of points I assigned to each click/pageview (it could be that some clicks do not have a number of points assigned), so for example:

```
id   points
1    10
1    N/A
1    30
2    100
3    20
3    10
```

Within the 'id' column, there are about 60000 unique values. What I want to achieve is, to count the number of points assigned to each 'id', and to let R do this automatically for all unique ids. So I'm looking for a result such as:

```
1 [40], 2 [100], 3[30]
```

However, I have absolutely no clue how to tell R to identify all unique ids and to do something (i.e. count points) within all these unique ids.

All help would be extremely appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: To apply `sum` see, also, `rowsum(data$points, data$id, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this using group by operations.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', we get the `sum` of 'points'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(points=sum(points, na.rm=TRUE)), by = id]
```

This could be also done with `aggregate` from `base R` or using `dplyr` methods.  Given the dataset is big, the `data.table` approach would be fast (`dplyr` is also fast).

NOTE: Assumptions are 1) the column 'points' is `numeric` class.  2) `N/A` is the real `NA`.

Comment: That is amazing, thanks so much! I never saw the setDT function, but will definitely look it up and learn more about it! Thanks!

Comment: It worked like a charm :) Ticked the box! I will definitely contribute to stackoverflow if I gain some more R knowledge.

Comment: Same as below, I'm getting curious now :) What would you do if you would again want to divide the points by the # of a specific id (so in case of id1, you'd have 40/3)? Would you make a new column counting the number of unique values in "id" and then make it somehow divide the count by the corresponding row in the new column?

Comment: @sfvisser  I think you need `mean` i.e. `setDT(df1)[, list(points=mean(points, na.rm=TRUE)), by = id]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer akrun!

Answer (score 1):

The `aggregate` option:

```
df$points <- as.numeric(as.character(df$points))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> aggregate(points ~ id, df, sum)
#  id points
#1  1     40
#2  2    100
#3  3     30
```

Based on OP's comment, we can get the `mean` by changing `NA` to `0`, and proceed with the same `aggregate` idea:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
aggregate(points ~ id, df, mean)
#  id    points
#1  1  13.33333
#2  2 100.00000
#3  3  15.00000
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), points = structure(c(1L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("10", "100", "20", "30", "N/A"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "points"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Also worked, thanks a lot! Just because this triggered my curiosity: what would you do if you would again want to divide the points by the # of a specific id (so in case of id1, you'd have 40/3)?

Comment: supernice, that worked really smoothly. Amazing how much you can do within R. Thanks for the support!